# At what point is an answer to a question considered late?

Tags: support, answers, late-answers

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099078/google-sheets-script-onselectionchanged/61804248#61804248) asked two and a half years ago because it is about a problem that has been solved this year. The answer has been reviewed as *late answer*.

Why is a response considered late when it provides a solution based on a [google apps script release note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases) from last April?

Comment: Please understand that a late answer is ***not* a bad thing**! It's just that statistics tell us that late answers are more likely to be spam or nonsense, especially when they're posted by new users, so we have folks review them just to make sure. If you're posting good answers, then that's great, regardless of the age of the question. (Literally. "Necroposting" is not a thing on SO. If you can add something new to the discussion, you should.)

Comment: I'm not upset, but I had 11 rep points and after my first answer I was deducted two.

Comment: That's easy to fix, as it should be.

Comment: It is not even bad if your post gets a review. Nearly anybody can initiate a review for anything. The problem is if the result of the review is false.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Or repeating existing answers (list of reasons).

Comment: Or using answers as comments (due to a forum mindset or too few reputation points to be able to comment).

Comment: @CodyGray *"If you can add something new to the discussion, you should."* I would be careful with such a statement. First of all Stack Overflow is not supposed to have discussions. Secondly, adding something new to the discussion can simply mean "I have this problem, too". If we want to answer any question we need to make sure that our contribution is useful.

Comment: "I have this problem, too" doesn't add anything new... Perhaps I should say "If you can add a new solution, you should."

Comment: From your title, I felt compelled to include that it seems an answer is late when the Question is 30 days old, see [How old does a question have to be for it to be a late answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177552/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The age of the answer doesn't really matter all that much.  So long as it's actually an answer, and is applicable to the subject matter at hand, it could be ten years old for all anyone cares.

The problem with *your* answer is that to the untrained eye, it's not enough of an answer.

> Good news. There is a new Simple Trigger, check this [release
>   note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#april_22_2020):
>
> > A new simple trigger, [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee), has been added for
> >     Google Sheets. The onSelectionChange(e) trigger runs automatically
> >     when a user changes the selection in a spreadsheet.

If I came across an answer like *that* in the queues, I'd probably think that there wasn't enough meat to it for the OP to get the answer they were looking for.  Taking about a minute out of my day to look closer, I can easily see that it *does* provide some kind of solution, I'd really want to see just a little bit more detail; maybe an example of how it's used.

Comment: I will give an example explaining how it is used. Wasn't the example I referenced via the link enough?

Comment: @JoanL:  No.  Imagine if the link disappeared tomorrow, and Stack Overflow was still running. What would be left of your answer?

Comment: Makoto can you add a sentence to the answer about question in the title in addition to addressing what @JoanL is actually asking? I don't know the exact "late" cut-off time, if you do - nice, otherwise something general "Late answer is an answer to any question that asked more than several weeks ago" would be useful addition to answer

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  My concern is that such a statement doesn't address the root of the OP's concerns, which was: their question was put into the Late Questions Review Queue and was downvoted.  Knowing the cutoff for when an answer goes into *any* review queue is immaterial in the face of, "how do I phrase this so that people won't downvote my answer if it winds up in that queue?"

Comment: @Makoto That's a valid point for this OP. But other users, like me, opened this Question because of curiosity about the cutoff time, which isn't completely unlikely to be expected of an answer to "At what point is an answer to a question considered late?"

Comment: @Scratte:  The reason I'm not addressing it is because it isn't really what's being asked.  The question is asking about age limits on an answer in context to the answer being poorly reviewed, not because of any mechanical question on the age of a question for reviews.

Answer (score -1):

You landed there because of [the time that has passed and your low rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work/161391#161391).

If you look at [the description](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) for the queue:

> This is a new user's answer to an old question.

Besides, answers should contain some explanation, not necessarily lengthy, so yours is somewhat short.